# Vue Router with Boolean Query Parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Problem: I have a component that needs a boolean value optionally passed to it as part of a call from within the view app and from an external app.  When I invoke the router directly I can pass the boolean with no issues but if I route by using the actual URL I get a parse warning.  To prevent the warning should I be using a string instead and parse it myself?

Router:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      name: 'Foo',
      component: Foo,
      props: (route) => ({ booleanParam: route.query.booleanParam })
    }
  ]
})
```

Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        BooleanParam: {{booleanParam}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Foo',
    props: {
        booleanParam: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Works:

```
router.push( { name: 'Foo', query: { booleanParam: true } })
```

Generates Warning:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo?booleanParam=true
```

Warning:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "booleanParam".
>   Expected Boolean, got String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a boolean is required by the component then parse the value as a Boolean before setting this as a prop:

```
props: (route) => ({ booleanParam: (route.query.booleanParam === 'true') })
```

This way the correct type is ensured.

---

**EDIT:**
As noted in the comment by the OP to support both String and Boolean the parameter could be converted to String to ensure both types work:

```
props: (route) => ({ booleanParam: (String(route.query.booleanParam). toLowerCase() === 'true') })
```

Comment: One caveat to this, if you're going to be doing a router.push with the boolean paramter you should do the following to support both paths:
props: (route) => ({ booleanParam: (route.query.booleanParam === 'true' || route.query.booleanParam === true) })

Answer (score 0):

have you try this

```
   const router = new VueRouter({
      routes: [
        { 
        path: '/foo',
        name:"Foo"
        component: Foo, props: (route) => ({ query: route.query.q }) }
      ]
    })

    OR

    {path:'/foo/:booleanParam', name:'Foo', component: Foo  }
```

Comment: I think the first part is what I've got in my question above. Since the parameter is optional foo/:boolean param won't work for my use case, hence the use of the query param.